# Need query for counting for 2 columns at a time

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a table named **"Orders"**

It has following fields:
**OrderID, OrderDate, ..... ,City, StatusID**.

I want this result as return:

```
City        No. of Delivered Orders, No. of Pending (Not Delivered)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
London      3                        4
Paris       5                        6
New York    7                        8
```

Since we have only one field to track the delivery status that is StatusID, so I am facing difficulty in order to count for two conditions at a time..

Thanx in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select City,
sum(case when StatusID = 'delivered' then 1 else 0 end) as [No. of Delivered Orders],
sum(case when StatusID = 'not_delivered' then 1 else 0 end) as [No. of Pending]
from Orders
```